# How can I change the color of one portion of a font icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I am implementing upvote button using `fa fa signs` and I was trying to color background of `up vote button` but the color is showing outside of the `sign` (which I think is the padding of icon), And i am trying to hide the outer padding. so the color will only be inside the upvote sign

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<i  class="fal voteup fa-sort-up fa-4x"></i>
```

```css
.voteup {
  background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<i  class="fal voteup fa-sort-up fa-4x"></i>
```

I have also tried by adding `padding: none;` but it is still showing.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Comment: Just use the filled icon character. No need to reinvent the wheel with a mechanical spider. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the black outline, you can use two icons (solid + regular) on top of each other:

```css
#outline {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

#background {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<i  class="fal voteup fa-sort-up fa-4x" id="outline"></i>
<i  class="fas voteup fa-sort-up fa-4x" id="background"></i>
```

Notice the order of HTML elements and `z-index`.

Comment: I recommend using the existing classes to style elements (or new custom classes). IDs in CSS are not reusable and tend to bloat your file _and_ your markup. Here you can use `.voteup` and `.voteup + .voteup`.

Comment: @isherwood Of course! You're right. I just used "id"s here to make them distinguishable from the rest of the code.

Comment: Always best to demonstrate good practices as a mentor. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a font, unfortunately - standard font files don't support multicolour fonts. (There is a new format that does, but it's not widely supported and Fontawesome isn't available that way in any case.)

If you want arrows that have an outer border in one colour and a fill in a different colour, you'll have to use an image. An SVG would probably be best (because vector graphics scale) and you can download the Fontawesome symbols as SVG files. You could then open the arrows in a graphics package like Inkscape and add your custom fill.

If you just want a solid arrow, you can use the Fontawesome solid variant. To do this, replace your `fal` class with `fas`.

Comment: Check out Shahriar's neat solution to this using two overlapping Fontawesome elements. If you want the border-with-fill option, that may be the best way to go, rather than creating your own custom SVG.

Comment: Thank You for Your Answer, And Yes i am checking it

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the properties of the filled icon character via CSS. This has the nice advantage of requiring no additional markup.

```css
.voteup {
  position: relative; /* allow absolute positioning of children */
}

.voteup:after {
  content: "\f0de"; /* set the character code */
  font-weight: 900; /* set the character variant */
  color: red;
  position: absolute; /* position with respect to the parent */
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1; /* since :before is in use, we'll use this and lay it behind */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hung1001/font-awesome-pro@4cac1a6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<i class="fal voteup fa-sort-up fa-4x"></i>
```

Comment: What?? Why didn't you just use the correct (filled) icon to begin with?

Comment: @Van If you don't want the outline, why don't you just use the solid type of fontawesome `fas` instead of `fal`?